# What is ".@checked" meaning and called?

Tags: c#, html, checked

When I read a source code C#, I see a line

```
return new Form(ElementType.Checkbox, ((IHTMLInputElement)htmlElement).@checked);
```

But I can NOT find it with keyword `.@checked`.
Could you please tell me what is `.@checked` called and its meaning?

**Update answer**
Firstly, Thanks @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev, @Erik Funkenbusch and @TcKs.
Secondly, I'm sorry for making duplicate post. Because I searched with ".@checked" and saw nothing.
Finally, I understood that `@` sign help define a variable whose name is as same as `C# keyword`, like this:

```
string @string = "This is a string";
string str = @string; // str = "This is a string"
```

Comment: It is just a property / member named `checked`. However, `checked` is C# keyword, so you have to use `@` to tell compiler that it is just member name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checked` is [keyword in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/74b4xzyw(v=vs.100).aspx) and therefore the name must be prefixed with `@` as documentation says:

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special
>   meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your
>   program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid
>   identifier but if is not because if is a keyword.

So `((IHTMLInputElement)htmlElement).@checked)` means accessing the `checked` member on instance of class implementing `IHTMLInputElement`.